# Install4j's default back button behaviour is incompatible with loops. What's the workaround?

Tags: loops, install4j

Can someone shed some light on how Install4j's back button actually works? I should note at this point that I'm using install4j Multi-Platform Edition 5.1.2 (build 5492).

**Loop Example**

This example is based on a screen group containing 2 screens ('Screen 1' and 'Screen 2').

1. Start screen
2. Screen 1 (in the looped group)
3. Screen 2 (in the looped group)
4. End screen

Screen group properties:

- Loop index start: 0
- Loop index step: 1
- Loop expression: (Integer)context.getVariable("i") < 2
- Loop index variable name: i

As expected, clicking next repeatedly results in the following screen flow:

1. Start screen
2. Screen 1 (i=0)
3. Screen 2 (i=0)
4. Screen 1 (i=1)
5. Screen 2 (i=1)
6. Screen 1 (i=2)
7. Screen 2 (i=2)
8. End screen

I would expect the back button to step backwards through the history listed above. However, the actual behaviour is as follows:

1. End screen
2. Screen 2 (i=3)
3. Screen 1 (i=3)
4. Screen 1 (i=3)
5. Screen 1 (i=3)
6. Start screen

Clearly this is not what any rational user would expect. To complicate matters further, the [change Log Install4j for 5.1 Build 5435](http://www.softpedia.com/progChangelog/install4j-Changelog-172405.html) includes the following:

> Fixed wrong behavior when going back in the screen history where
>   screen loops were present

The other issue raised in this example, is how do you decrement the loop counter when stepping backwards? It would appear there's no practical way of doing this when using a looped screen group.

If this is case, the only way of implementing a loop which can be stepped through backwards is to implement your own screens in order to override [previous()](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/screens/Screen.html#previous%28%29). The side effect being that you have to hand code your screens just to get the correct back button behaviour for loops, which seems ridiculous.

Has anyone else found a decent workaround for this problem? The install4j manual is pretty lame in that the word 'history' only appears once. There's no specification for how the back button works whatsoever.

Comment: Because the looping functionality doesn't behave as expected, I'm now looking at solving this problem by directly manipulating the Install4j project file. For example, if I have 3 databases to configure I will simply duplicate the required screens in the project XML, thus avoiding the need to do any looping at all. This isn't ideal but I feel it's the simplest solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, it will be fixed in 5.1.4. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get the current build where it is fixed.

> The other issue raised in this example, is how do you decrement the
>   loop counter when stepping backwards? It would appear there's no
>   practical way of doing this when using a looped screen group.

This will work automatically in 5.1.4.

Comment: Thanks Ingo. Like I said, I'll go with manipulating the project XML in the meantime as it also saves having to dynamically bind UI controls to indexed properties.